# angular ng-if with bootstrap popover not working

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

```
<div class="form-group" ng-if="firstname">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input readonly type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" ng-model="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
    <a href="" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="focus" data-content="User Name" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign infottp"></a>
</div>
```

I am using above code. From that i am displaying a popover by clicking -info-sign glyphicon, i am using ng-if condition for show/hide instead of ng-show and ng-hide.My problem is when i use ng-if, popover is not working.But popover working in ng-hide condition and if i remove ng-if condition.My question is why popover not working in ng-if condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gotcha! is, `ng-if` prevents DOM Element from being rendered, where as `ng-show / ng-hide` only changes `display` css-poperty

please refer first paragraph of angular documents for [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

Comment: you mean ng-if completely removes display css-property right

Comment: ng-if prevents HTML element itself from being rendered.

Comment: Yes, in your scenario it is apt. Whenever you have something on DOM which will show/hide often you should use ng-show, but in situations where element has to be permanently removed, use ng-if

Comment: ng-if is adds/removes entire DOM element, thus it is heavier that ng-show/ng-hide

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example that demostrate how ng-if works

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.firstname = "Test Data";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
    <div ng-if="lastname"></div>
    <div class="form-group" ng-if="firstname">
      <label>First Name</label>
      <input readonly type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" ng-model="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
      <label>Last Name</label>
      <input readonly type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" ng-model="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```